# How can I make my setTimeouts get stopped here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is this:

On hover/mouseenter, change the background image from the placeholder to a gif whose positions changes in order to achieve an animated effect, then go back to the placeholder when the mouse leaves.

My code is

```
    $('.filmstrip').mouseenter(function(){
        var $that = $(this),
               w = $that.width(),
              fr = $that.attr('data-framerate');
        $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-gifurl')+')');
        for ( var i = 1, n = $that.attr('data-ticks'); i <= n; ++i )
        {
            (function(j){
               setTimeout(function(){
                  $that.css('background-position-x','-'+(w*j)+'px');
               }, j*fr);
            })(i);
        }
        $that.bind('mouseleave',function(){
            $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-placeholder')+')').css('background-position-x','0');
        });
    });
```

and the bug I'm having is that if the gif hasn't finished animating, then the

```
.css('background-position-x','0')
```

part of

```
$that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-placeholder')+')').css('background-position-x','0');
            });
```

doesn't work because the background position is still being moved by the animation. So I need some way to first stop the `setTimeout` stuff if it isn't finished running. Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be something better done with CSS rather than javascript.

### Option #1 - Use an actual GIF

You could compile the frames which you want animated into an actual GIF file, and then have the background image change based on hover:

```
<div class="filmstrip"></div>
```

And then CSS

```
.filmstrip { background:transparent url('static_image.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 }
.filmstrip:hover { background-image:url( 'animated_image.gif' ) }
```

### Option #2 - Use CSS3 Animation

You could keep the animated image as a strip of frames (of a known length) and then use something like:

```
<div class="filmstrip"></div>
```

With CSS

```
.filmstrip { background:transparent url('static_image.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 }
@keyframes animate-bg {  
    0% { background-position: 0 0 }
  100% { background-position: -1000px 0 }
  /* where 1000px is the length of the strip */
}
.filmstrip:hover { animation: animate-bg 5s steps(50) infinite }
/* where 5s is the overall loop length time and 50 is the number of frames in the strip */
```

### Option #3 - Use [Spritely](http://spritely.net/)

Spritely is a jQuery plugin which seems to manage all elements of turning a filmstrip/sprite image into an animation, including being able to start/stop the animation, reset to the first frame, change FPS, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Add a stop variable :

```
$('.filmstrip').mouseenter(function(){
    var isStopped = false;
    var $that = $(this),
           w = $that.width(),
          fr = $that.attr('data-framerate');
    $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-gifurl')+')');
    for ( var i = 1, n = $that.attr('data-ticks'); i <= n && !isStopped; ++i )
    {
        (function(j){
           setTimeout(function(){
              if (!isStopped) {
                  $that.css('background-position-x','-'+(w*j)+'px');
              }
           }, j*fr);
        })(i);
    }
    $that.bind('mouseleave',function(){
        isStopped = true;
        $that.css('background-image','url('+$that.attr('data-placeholder')+')').css('background-position-x','0');
    });
});
```

If isStopped is not accessible (because not tested) from the timeout, then just create a new variable in a inner scope which you affect isStopped value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interval based solution like

```js
$('.filmstrip').mouseenter(function() {
  var $that = $(this),
    w = $that.width(),
    fr = +$that.attr('data-framerate'),
    ticks = +$that.attr('data-ticks');
  $that.css('background-image', 'url(' + $that.attr('data-gifurl') + ')');

  var counter = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $that.css('background-position-x', '-' + (w * ++counter) + 'px');
    if (counter >= ticks) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, fr);
  $(this).data('bg-interval', interval)
}).mouseleave(function() {
  clearInterval($(this).data('bg-interval'));
  $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).attr('data-placeholder') + ')').css('background-position-x', '0');
});
```

```css
.filmstrip {
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-position: right;
  background-position-y: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filmstrip" data-framerate="400" data-ticks="10" data-gifurl="//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=bc7c2f3904bf">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use `clearTimeout` to stop `setTimeOut`.

### Working Demo-

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the first button to alert "Hello" after waiting 3 seconds.</p>
<p>Click the second button to prevent the first function to execute. (You must click it before the 3 seconds are up.)</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop the alert</button>
```

### More-

**[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout)**

and

**[W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)**